# How is this tuple-valued function written in arrow notation?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $r: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$,
then suppose $T(x) = ( f(x), r(x) ) : x \in \mathbb{R}$.

How is the function $T$ written in arrow notation? Is
$$
T : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}
$$
correct?

Comment: Do you really mean $\{f(x), r(x) \}$ to be a set? In that case if $f(0)=0$ and $r(0)=0$, then $T(0)=\{0\}$, a singleton. Is that really what you want, or is it supposed to be a tuple $(f(x),r(x))$ instead?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne No, I meant it to be a 2-tuple, which I've realised now should be written as $(f(x), r(x))$.

Comment: Your second suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $r : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $T(x) = (f(x), r(x))$, then $T$'s arrow notation definition is
$$
T : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}.
$$